# How can I prevent sympy from introducing imaginary numbers?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I am using sympy to do symbolic integration:

```
var("x", real = True)
var("a", real = True, negative = True)
integrate(exp(a * x**2), (x, -oo, +oo))

> I*sqrt(pi)/sqrt(a)
```

I would have expected to get `sqrt(pi)/sqrt(-a)` instead. Why are imaginary numbers being introduced and how can I prevent this? Given that `a` is negative, I find `sqrt(-a)` preferable over `I/sqrt(a)`.

I dug further and found the following:

```
var("x", real = True)
var("a", real = True, negative = True)
sqrt(pi / a)

> sqrt(pi)*(I/sqrt(-a))
```

I found this even more puzzling, having expected the expression `sqrt(pi / a)` to stay unchanged, as there is no simplification or other complicated operation happening. Why is this happening?

Why are imaginary numbers being introduced? Is there a way to force using real numbers throughout the computation?

Comment: You say "even though all of the expressions are real" but `sqrt(a)` is not real.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin I was referring to the first example, but I think that comment was confusing, so I removed it.